# Salvar parâmetro php em variável vba

Tags: php, microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba, exec

Tenho um `form` que passo um parâmetro e ao mesmo tempo abre uma planilha de Excel.
 Segue exemplo:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET["param"]) && !empty($_GET["param"])) {
    $param =  $_GET["param"]; 
    exec("START teste.xlsx $param");   
}else{  
    echo "Não foi enviado parâmetro.";
}
?>

<form method="GET" action="#">
    <input type="text" id="param" name="param">
    <button type="submit"> ABRIR EXCEL </button>
</form>
```

Como faço para guardar esse parâmetro em uma variável no vba do Excel para poder utiliza-lo ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boa tarde.
Você pode usar o método que está descrito neste artigo http://www.excelflex.com.br/avancado-ler-o-parametro-da-linha-de-comando-pelo-vba/

Complementando a resposta:

```
#If Win64 Then
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetCommandLineL Lib "kernel32" _
    Alias "GetCommandLineA" () As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function lstrcpyL Lib "kernel32" _
    Alias "lstrcpyA" (ByVal lpString1 As String, ByVal lpString2 As LongPtr) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function lstrlenL Lib "kernel32" _
    Alias "lstrlenA" (ByVal lpString As LongPtr) As Long
#Else
Private Declare Function GetCommandLineL Lib "kernel32" _
    Alias "GetCommandLineA" () As Long
Private Declare Function lstrcpyL Lib "kernel32" _
    Alias "lstrcpyA" (ByVal lpString1 As String, ByVal lpString2 As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function lstrlenL Lib "kernel32" _
    Alias "lstrlenA" (ByVal lpString As Long) As Long
#End If

Function GetCommandLine() As String
  Dim strReturn As String
  #If Win64 Then
  Dim lngPtr As LongPtr
  #Else
  Dim lngPtr As Long
  #End If
  Dim StringLength As Long
  'Get the pointer to the commandline string
  lngPtr = GetCommandLineL
  'get the length of the string (not including the terminating null character):
  StringLength = lstrlenL(lngPtr)
  'initialize our string so it has enough characters including the null character:
  strReturn = String$(StringLength + 1, 0)
  'copy the string we have a pointer to into our new string:
  lstrcpyL strReturn, lngPtr
  'now strip off the null character at the end:
  GetCommandLine = Left$(strReturn, StringLength)
End Function
```

Comment: Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o link para referência.  As respostas apenas por link podem ser invalidadas se a página com o link for alterada. - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/191480)

Comment: @rLinhares, obrigado pela dica. Incluí o conteúdo na resposta.